# converting custom field date format

Tags: custom-field, date-time

I am using the More Fields plugin which gives me the ability to create a date formatted YYYY/mm/dd  and I want to convert that to be shown like: February 11, 2011

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have issue with exactly converting or retrieval? Converting is trivial and is plain PHP:

```
date('F j, Y', strtotime($date));
```

For more complex and WordPress-specific way with localization support see [`date_i18n()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) function.

Comment: Rarst, this looks right but I am having trouble making it work 100%.  
$date = meta('event_date');
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($date));
returns January 1 1970.... ideas?

Comment: @tjsherrill ehm, I don't think `meta()` is native function?.. Are you sure you get sane string value in `$date`?

Comment: I got it, meta(); is a template tag provided by the more-fields plugin.  I simply used get_post_meta and it works great. thanks

Comment: This isn't working for me. My custom field is "date-time-last" 
$date = get_post_meta('date-time-last'); echo date('l jS F Y', strtotime($date));

Comment: @Pete check the values you are getting and stuff, "isn't working" is a little vague. :)

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness, I just realised that after my 5th edit so i was unable to further update it... I kept on getting "1 January 1970". In any case I've found a solution that works... <?php $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date-time-last', true); if($date != ''){echo date("l jS F Y", strtotime($date));} ?>

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (inside the loop)...

```
<?php $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'CUSTOM-FIELD-HERE', true); if($date != ''){echo date("l jS F Y", strtotime($date));} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = '2000/10/28';
$a = preg_split ( '/\//', $date );
echo date('F j, Y', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $a[1], $a[2], $a[0] ) );
```